# Website building technique, place image in background, tracing image

Tags: html, css, image, trace

I'm not sure where to look for something like this. Basically I had the idea that if you could place the photoshop design as a background that was semi transparent and build over it. Using the image as a guide, almost like tracing. This way it would be easy to line things up. I believe microsoft expression (like dreamweaver) had a feature like this built in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295031.aspx. For my needs I just created a div at the bottom of my code and gave it some css like this.

```
#guide {
background-image: url('/BRSS_hm-V3.jpg');
background-position: top;
height: 1500px;
opacity: .20;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 1;
width: 100%;
}
```

Im wondering if anyone else is doing anything like this and if so what they would recommend. Also, could there be a better way to do this?

Comment: An interesting idea, would be nice to see what answers people come up with

Comment: I'm using ruler and two monitors :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, you can try the PixelPerfect extension:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/perfectpixel-by-welldonec/dkaagdgjmgdmbnecmcefdhjekcoceebi

(I think there's an extension for Firefox as well, with the same name)

Comment: That looks good. In my case im using a program called Stylizer which is basically a visual CSS editor. So I would not be able to use this plugin. So far my raw css solution seems to work, although I've had to place position relative and z index on a few items that I would normally not.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver has had a tracing image option since about 2000.

I wouldn't recommend DreamWeaver for any other reason, but this particular feature, it has.

Failing that, adding `pointer-events: none` to your code above would be good, because then you could interact with the browser without the image overlay covering all the controls.

Comment: Sweet! love when that magical CSS code you never heard of appears and saves the day!

Comment: Yeah, it's a good one.  Unfortunately, it has minimal browser support, so in a production environment it's not as useful.  But for your particular problem it's very useful indeed.

If you need to pass mouse events through a block element otherwise, you have to mess around with JS event capture and such.